# Best age for watching "Once Upon a Time..."-like series

Tags: pre-schooler, age-appropriate, television

I have 3-4 full series of "Once Upon a Time...", for example "[Once Upon a Time... Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time..._Life)". I played it to my 5 years old daughter and she didn't find it interesting. That isn't much surprising for me, but I'd like to know about best age, when I should consider another attempt with this?

Would 7 years be better? Or maybe 9? Or maybe even more? Maybe this is teenagers-oriented serie?

Comment: I had to sign up, just to write this comment. I watched this series as a kid. I am sure I started watching and liking it at the age of about 8 or 9, but the most loved memories I have of watching it at biology classes in school at the age of 12. I strongly blame re-watching it at age 12 being an influence of my choice of career. At 5 I imagine it would have been cute, but quite confusing and way too much (hidden) information. I was also horribly scared of the episode where the kid got tetanus at a young age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that particular series, but our 5 and 7 year-olds watch a wide variety of science and history shows intended for all ages.  A lot of it goes over their heads, but they generally enjoy them and ask good questions that show a certain understanding.

For example, we recently watched an adult-targeted documentary on the atomic bombs at Hiroshima and Nagasaki.  They didn't understand the larger context, but they learned where Japan was on a map, they learned a little about war, and they learned that the bombs were horrible but ended a war that was horrible.

My kids are not geniuses.  Their attention is as fickle as any child's, moreso in the case of my son.  They usually prefer shows about princesses or super heroes.  There are a few things we do to get them interested in these kinds of shows:

- Show them regularly, a few times a week at least.  The kids should see it as a normal occurrence instead of something strange and new you're forcing on them.
- Show them right before bed, when they are already winding down for the day, a little bit bored, and looking for more passive entertainment.
- Recognize topics the kids bring up, and choose shows that elaborate on those topics.  Kids ask a *lot* of questions out of the blue.  For example, we were shopping yesterday and my son suddenly wondered how many different animals there were in the world.  That's a good opportunity to present a nature show about the many species in rain forests, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, may be teenagers or pre teens  would be more appropriate.
But, I dont blame your daughter as even I dont like it & find it not so interesting.
I think other than the age and maturity, even the child's preferences, liking and attitude plays a pivotal role.

Answer (score 1):

Though I didn't find "Once Upon a Time" there, a great resource for getting age recommendations for movies/tv/games/books is [Common Sense Media](http://commonsensemedia.org) They provide parents' recommendations and kids' recommendations and a break down of what's in a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I love this and am 13. My 10 year old brother loves it and my 7 year old cousin! The worst words said are "ass" "crap" "bloody" that is literally it. There is slight violence but think about it, every fairy tail ever invented is pretty brutal. But it shows sword fights with princes and ogres and stuff. But u don't see anything that gory or violent. Anybody can watch it in my opinion

Comment: This question wasn't about the [TV show dramatizing fairy tales](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1843230/) which your answer supports, but rather the [French animated educational series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time...). Welcome anyway :)